# Advantages and disadvantages of using application variables in web applications

Tags: asp.net

I haven't used the application variables in my asp.net web applications. I'm using asp.net2.0. Is there any disadvantages of using applicationvariables.

Comment: Do you mean variables saved in the Application collection? If so, Mirosoft states that it is wiser to use static variables instead. Actually I agree that using static variables is more comfortable than the Application collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by application variables?  Like:

```
private int _key = 0;
```

If so, these kinds of variables are not saved between web requests.  When the page unloads, and you have to use session or cache or viewstate to store it like:

```
ViewState["Key"] = 1;
```

or

```
Session["Key"] = 1;
```

And reload it from here when the page loads again.  If you mean something else, please comment and I'll update my response.

**EDIT:** For application, check these out:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2003/12/01/40526.aspx
- http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ApplicationState05102005051501AM/ApplicationState.aspx

Application state is application-wide storage, and so to limit to a user, you need to append the user ID to the key, or use session.

Comment: Sorry ... I mean the 'Aplication Variables', not the view state or session